# Symfony2 - contact FormBuilder. Variable form does not exist in twig template. One site page

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I am sitting three hours under symfony2 FormBuilder, when I try to make a simple contact form, on my OneSitePage website. I will notice that I am mostly frontend, but I need send emails via Swiftmailer across symfony2. Please do not ask, why I am using symfony:)

PROBLEM: I have issue with render form on my homePage, because Symfony says, like in subject:

**"Variable "form" does not exist in YodaHomeBundle::layout.html.twig..."**
and it point for line where I am useing twig form(attached below in TWIG section)

Ok, that was introduction. Below I present PHP class of controller and ContactType class, also below I had attached layout.html.twig file.

First comes controller, where I have two actions, index and contact.

```
namespace Yoda\HomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Yoda\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Yoda\HomeBundle\Form\ContactType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


class HomeController extends Controller{

    /**
      * @Route("/home", name="homePage")
      * @Template()
      *
      */
    public function indexAction(){

        return $this->render('YodaHomeBundle::layout.html.twig');

    }

    public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

        $adress = 'grzegorz.developer@gmail.com';

        if($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));

            if($form->isValid())
            {
                $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
                    ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
                    ->setTo($adress)
                    ->setBody(
                        $this->renderView('@YodaHome/mail/contact.html.twig',
                            array(
                                'ip'        =>  $request->getClientIp(),
                                'name'      =>  $form->get('name')->getData(),
                                'message'   =>  $form->get('message')->getData()
                            ))
                    );

                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('Success, your mail has been send! Thank you, I will back to you, as soon as it\'s possible!');

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homePage'));

            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );

    }

}
```

now builder, Simple builder which is used on many tuts.

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder'   => 'What\'s your name?',
                'length'        => '.{2,}'
            )
        ))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder'   => 'So I can write back to you'
            )
        ))
        ->add('subject', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder'   => 'Subject of your message',
                'pattern'       => '.{5,}'
            )
        ))
        ->add('message', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'cols'          => '90',
                'row'           => '10',
                'placeholder'   => 'And ad your message to me...'
            )
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'You forgot about the Name.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 2))
            ),
            'email' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Email should not be blank.')),
                new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address.'))
            ),
            'subject' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Subject should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 3))
            ),
            'message' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Message should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 5))
            )
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'homePage';
    }
```

And for last place routing and TWIG:

```
mail_create:
    path:     /homePage
    defaults: { _controller: "YodaHomeBundle:Home:contact" }
    requirements: { _method: post }

[...]
    <form action="{{ path('mail_create') }}" method="post">
                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
    </form>
[...]
```

Please for support, everywhere are solutions for different routes for contact, and I have everything on one page. All hints are welcome, please for comments!

Uland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need render your form on layout twig by:

```
 public function indexAction(){
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    return $this->render('YodaHomeBundle::layout.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView());

}
```

Or you can split layout, one controller is one layout:

Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

/**
  * @Route("/home", name="homePage")
  * @Template()
  *
  */
public function indexAction(){

    return $this->render('YodaHomeBundle::layout.html.twig');

}

public function contactAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    // do your code

    return array(
        'YodaHomeBundle::contactlayout.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView());

}
```

}

And for TWIG:
layout.html.twig:

```
[..]
<div>{{ render(controller('YodaHomeBundle:Home:contact')) }}</div>
[..]
```

contactlayout.html.twig:

```
[..]
    <form action="{{ path('mail_create') }}" method="post">
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {{ form_end(form) }}
    </form>
[..]
```

Comment: Thank you @HAD! You're a Boss, really! It is working now. I consider that I can remove createView from contactAction now, because it is loaded from indexAction now.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't pass to your view the form object created in your controller because you don't call your contact controller.

If it's a one page, creat a twig view named `contact.html.twig` with your form and add in your index twig template where you want render the form :

```
{{ render(controller('YodaHomeBundle:Home:contact')) }}
```

This twig method will call your `indexController` and the `contactAction`